# Phonegap Android Alert notification not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using PhoneGap Build to make an app for Android and Windows Phone. I'm trying to show a notification using the Alert function in JavaScript. The app works perfectly by showing the alert when i open it in a browser or install it on my Windows Phone but it fails on Android. 
I have tried using the following functions to show a notification; however none of them seem to work:

```
navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working", function(){}, "", ""); 
navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working"); 
alert('We were unable to use location services in order to determine your location.');
```

I also added the following to the config.xml one at a time to add the notification plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.Notification" /> // generated an error on PhoneGap Build

<feature name="Notification">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />

<gap:plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: you don't have to install notification plugin, the alert it on the dialogs plugin, install it with this line `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm"/>`